# Sangria-graphql: error when passing in derivedInputObjectType as an mutation argument

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have the following case class with option fields:

```
case class BusinessUserRow(id: String, firstName: Option[String], lastName: Option[String], email: Option[String])
```

I am trying to create an inputType Object for Business User Object

```
val BusinessUserInputType =
    deriveInputObjectType[BusinessUserRow](
      InputObjectTypeName("input"),
      InputObjectTypeDescription("A Business user")
    )
```

and I want to pass this BusinessInputObject as an argument to a addBusinessUser mutation

```
  val businessUserInputArg = Argument("input", BusinessUserInputType)

val Mutation = ObjectType("Mutation", fields[RepoContext, Unit](
    Field("addBusinessUser", BusinessUserType,
      arguments = businessUserInputArg :: Nil,
      resolve = c ⇒ c.ctx.BusinessUserRepo.create(c.arg(businessUserInputArg)))))
```

But I get the following compilation error:

```
Type dao.Tables.BusinessUserRow @@ sangria.marshalling.FromInput.InputObjectResult cannot be used as an input. Please consider defining an implicit instance of `FromInput` for it.
[error]   val businessUserInputArg = Argument("input", BusinessUserInputType)
```

But All fields in BusinessRow are scalar values. I don't understand what is causing the issue.Is there something I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deserialize the input in the `BusinessUserRow` case class, you need to provide an instance of `FromInput[BusinessUserRow]` type class. You can find more docs on it here:

http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#frominput-type-class

So if you are, for instance, using spray-json, then you need to define `JsonFormat` for `BusinessUserRow`

Answer (score 0):

thanks! just adding this line solved my problem:

```
implicit val businessUserFormat = Json.format[BusinessUserRow]
```